# Compatibility Of CAES

Tags: energy-storage

I would like to know with which existing types of power plants(thermal,wind,etc.) can compressed air energy storage(CAES) be used efficiently? And how can it aid power plants like thermal(a brief explanation is sufficient)?

As far as I know it requires multiple compressors and hence can be used with a gas turbine power plant. But why would a gas turbine need CAES since it can readily obtain air and compress it at any time?

Comment: Are you asking about which existing plants can have a CAES system added to them?  That doesn't really make sense. It is a completely separate system in itself. It is similar to asking, "Which power plants can solar panels be added to?"

Comment: see my answer, CAES power gas turbines and I think the question (that could be written more clearly) is about why that is so. Adnan, you can edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical CAES plants (all two of them currently in operation) need a heat source to generate power: The gas cools with expansion, thus loosing pressure, they need to heat it to realise all the potential energy. One way around his is to combine the CAES with a gas turbine, the air is mixed with gas and undergoes combustion in the turbine. So in effect the CAES provides the work otherwise neccessary for compression of the combustion air.

You probably could use this with other heat engines. But CAES are built for grid balancing where you want to adjust the output of your plant quickly, and quickest engines in this regard are gas turbines.

This is the system in place in the plants Huntdorf (Germany) and McIntosh (USA).

Contrast with adiabatic CAES, where the heat from compression is stored and reused when generating power. The furthest developed project along these lines, ADELE in Staßfurt (Germany), was canceled recently though.

Source: [wikipedia Druckluftspeicherkraftwerk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druckluftspeicherkraftwerk#Druckluft-Gas-Kombikraftwerk)

Answer (score 1):

> But why would a gas turbine need CAES since it can readily obtain air and compress it at any time?

Power plants that are operated by solar power can't "obtain" compressed air at any time as you say. For example solar tower power plants can't operate at all time of day without energy storage system, so at times of solar peak when the plant can deliver more power than its actual load, it stores this excess power for the times when the solar power input is minimum (or vanishes).

I hope you find this picture of an hourly performance of a hybrid gas turbine useful (check the power solar to turbine curve along the hours of the day).

[Source: Algeria: a case study for solarised gas turbine systems - Gertig et al.]

[image]